# Difference between “à un moment ou (l'autre / un autre / à un autre)”

Tags: choix-de-mot, articles, indications-de-temps, coordination

I believe this is the expression for “at some point” or “at one point or another”. I've seen it written multiple ways:

> 1. à un moment ou **l'autre**
> 2. à un moment ou **un autre**
> 3. à un moment ou **à un autre**

Is there a difference between them or are they interchangeable?

Comment: In Québec I often hear `À un moment donné` for *At one point or another* It is often abbreviated to something the can be read like *`À madné`*. Your three sentences though seem correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, they are interchangeable, but 2 and 3 have the "advantage" not to mix a definite and an undefinite particle.